# wont go to login screen

Tags: boot

i installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for the first time removing windows
while installing i created partition for /boot /root /home and swap of 1GB , 20GB , about39GB, 4GB respectively. a dilouge box said ubuntu was successfully installed and asked for a reboot, but it wont load up.
little dots below ubuntu logo move for few seconds and stops, a mouse pointer aslo appears but dosent move and it freezes the same way.
grub menu seems fine, i can log in from recovery mode. i also tried fsck , dkpg from recovery mode but it dosent work.
i dont know what to do
i hope someone will help :)

edit: yeah and all my other partions(except the ones i installed ubuntu) has become read only i dont know how to fix them either
LOTS OF PROBLEM HERE

processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5800 @ 3.20GHz × 2
RAM:2GB
64-BIT OS

[this is where it freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlsy1.jpg)
[fsck report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXDUk.jpg)
[system summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH8FF.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Askubuntu! Before we get started, please edit your post with more information about your system (specs, hardware, etc.), any logs that the system reports. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a graphics driver problem. In recovery mode, try going to `Software and Updates`, and then click `Additional Drivers` and see if there's any drivers to install.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Comment: you are awsome!
i can log in now
i fixed read only problem using sudo ntfsfix.
all problems solved thanks to you

Comment: @icant69 Glad it worked for you. Please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!